# Create batch file to copy entire directory to new variable directory

Tags: batch-file

Here's my problem.  Playing a PC game (Arkham City) that can sometimes corrupt the save out of nowhere.  My idea is to copy the save data to a new directory (as opposed to overwriting it) every time I start the game.  In fact, this batch file will do everything.  Copy files to new directory, and execute the game.  I want it to copy all of the files to a variable directory every time I execute the batch into a new folder like Backup1, Backup2, etc.

There are two directories this games uses for save data - need them both:
C:\Users\Daddy\Documents\WB Games
C:\Users\Daddy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\XLive

Those directories and subdirectories when then copy to a location like this:

C:\Users\Daddy\Documents\Batman\GameSaveData\Backup1\   where the value after 1 is the variable.  So literally every time I execute this batch, it dumps a new set of save data into a new Backup% folder at that directory.

The example below is static, but just overwrites to same directory.  Unfortunately I wouldn't know if my game was corrupted until I go to play, but by then, the batch will have overwritten the good save with the corrupted save.  This is why I want to always dump into a new backup folder.

`xcopy "C:\Users\Daddy\Documents\WB Games" "C:\Users\Daddy\Documents\Batman\GameSaveData\WB Games" /D /E /C /R /I /K /Y /S`

xcopy "C:\Users\Daddy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\XLive" "C:\Users\Daddy\Documents\Batman\GameSaveData\XLive" /D /E /C /R /I /K /Y /S

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WB Games\Batman Arkham City GOTY\Binaries\Win32\BmLauncher.exe"

Comment: I tend to prefer robocopy instead of xcopy, but an idea would be to append a datetime to the of each directory you are copying to, so it's different each time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you substring %date% and %time% to a yyyymmddhhmmss variable and use that in place of 1,2 etc.

Quite how you'd do that would depend on your date and time formats, but it's documented extensively on SO.

Using the yyyymmddhhmmss format will mean that the last directory in a `dir` list would be the last chronologically...

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

(will create a subfolder in "%Userprofile%\Documents\Batman\GameSaveData" named YYYY-MM-DD_HourMinuteSecond and copy the contents to it)

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "SKIP=1 TOKENS=1-7" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
   IF NOT "%%~F" == "" (
      SET YYYY=%%F
      SET MM=00%%D
      SET DD=00%%A
      SET HH=00%%B
      SET Min=00%%C
      SET Sec=00%%E
    )
)

SET friendlyTime=%YYYY%-%MM:~-2%-%DD:~-2%_%HH:~-2%%Min:~-2%%Sec:~-2%
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
IF NOT EXIST "%Userprofile%\Documents\Batman\GameSaveData\%friendlyTime%" MD "%Userprofile%\Documents\Batman\GameSaveData\%friendlyTime%"
ENDLOCAL 

XCOPY "%Userprofile%\Documents\WB Games" "%Userprofile%\Documents\Batman\GameSaveData\%friendlyTime%\WB Games" /D /E /C /R /I /K /Y /S
XCOPY "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\XLive" "%Userprofile%\Documents\Batman\GameSaveData\%friendlyTime%\XLive" /D /E /C /R /I /K /Y /S
```

Edit:
i haven't checked your XCOPY-Commandline, just copy and pasted it. :)

Comment: Baba - working after a small tweak.  Was just creating folder, but wasn't copying anything into it.  Removing "ECHO" from the front of the xcopy lines did the trick.  Also separated the folders they go in by adding friendlytime1 & 2.  Thank you so much, works just how I needed.

Comment: Trying to post final code, but not understanding how to post code here.  Telling me I have too many characters...  Says something about <pre><code> block?  Tried <pre><code> "code here" </code></pre> but still tells me too many characters...

Comment: Code must be surronded by Grave accents (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent). 
I've deleted the "ECHO"s. They were just for testing on my machine. 

If now everything is fine, please feel free to mark it as Answer. :)